# What would you call a specialised object unique to a person?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I was hoping to get some help with a general word or phrase meaning or specifying an object unique to its owner. E.g. A special sword owned by a knight, a special instrument owned by a musician, or a unique book owned by a magician.

Ideas that come to mind but aren't quite right are:

- Talisman
- Totem
- instrument (probably closest but doesn't portray the importance I want it to)

Comment: The broadened sense of _trademark_ ('something very noticeable that a person typically has or does') ([CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trademark)) would perhaps work were it not for the clash of registers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -  Yes, I had been thinking *signature* in the same sense.

Comment: Possibly _bespoke_. That means made to order, and the ordering is where the "spoke" comes in. Of course, that's the term from a maker's point of view; from a user's point of view it might not work. Though "bespoke tailoring" has some of the right feel, in a land where there's no magic except advertising.

Comment: A talisman is a good luck charm of sorts, not specialized. A totem is a symbol representing you.

Comment: @Jim [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/signature) endorses the nounal usage << **signature** [noun] 3. 
a. a distinctive mark, characteristic, etc, that identifies a person or thing >>, though I'm sure the attributive usage is far more common for this sense. I'm not sure whether this would be a good answer, but it's perhaps as near as one can get. Of course, the default sense of the noun conflicts (if not as badly as with 'trademark').

Comment: Consider [_prized/treasured possession_](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/possession).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TV tropes calls it an [Iconic Item](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IconicItem).

Within the text they also use "signature item", which I feel may be an even better fit:

> Early in [The Fourth Doctor's] run the production team had intended his yo-yo to be his **signature item** (note its prominent use in "The Ark in Space"), but it didn't stick.

Just "signature" alone has the potential to be confused with a [John Hancock](https://grammarist.com/phrase/john-hancock-and-john-henry/) (though you could say that John Hancock's John Hancock is his signature item, a signature).

Comment: I was about to suggest *signature item*. This Wikipedia entry ([Signature weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_weapon)) also dances around both *signature* and *trademark*: "A signature weapon (or trademark weapon or weapon of choice) is one commonly identified with a certain group or, in the case of literature, comics, and film, where it is a popular trope, for both heroes and villains to be associated with and highly proficient in the use of specific weaponry." So the *batarang* might be Batman's signature weapon; not a big stretch to say *signature item*.